# VB.NET Incorrect HTML from Outlook Item .HTMLBody

Tags: html, vb.net, html-table, outlook, mshtml

I'm trying to replicate a VBA function I made into VB.NET.
it basically gets a mail and then it extracts its TABLE tag from its HTMLBody.
My issue is that the functions give a different output.
VBA's returns a standard HTML format, with all the tags, TABLE included.
VB.NET's output instead is the one below.

```
<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->
<P><FONT SIZE=2>TEXT0,<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
INTRO:<BR>
<BR>
A. TEXT1<BR>
<BR>
B TEXT2<BR>
<BR>
C. TEXT3<BR>
<BR>
D. TEXT4<BR>
<BR>
E. TEXT5 &amp; TEXT6<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
```

This instead what I would like to have

```
<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='word-wrap:break-word'><div class=WordSection1><p><span style='font-family:Arial'>TEXT0<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p><span style='font-family:Arial'><br>INTRO <o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p><span style='font-family:Arial'>A. TEXT1 <o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p><span style='font-family:Arial'>B. TEXT2 <o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p><span style='font-family:Arial'>C. TEXT3 <o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p><span style='font-family:Arial'>D. TEXT4 <o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='font-family:Arial'>E. TEXT5
```

I already tried all the BodyFormats, the result is almost the same, no standard HTML.
The references used in both are the same.
Below the code.

```
Function GetMailTable(Subject As String, daysAgo As Integer, ParamArray Keywords() As Object)
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim Subj As String = Subject
    Dim arrList As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    daysAgo = myDate.Subtract(previousBusinessDay(myDate, daysAgo)).TotalDays
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & Subj & "%'"
    Dim filtereditemssubj As Object = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Dim filteredItems As Object = filtereditemssubj.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(myDate.AddDays(-daysAgo), "dd/MM/yyyy") + " 00:00" & "'")
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]<'" & Format(myDate.AddDays(-daysAgo).AddDays(1), "dd/MM/yyyy") + " 00:00" & "'")
    Dim htmlDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim tables As mshtml.DispHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Table As mshtml.HTMLTable
    If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then
        Found = False
    Else
        Found = True
        For Each itm In filteredItems
            htmlDoc.HTMLBody = itm.HTMLBody
            tables = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
            For Each Table In tables
                arrList.Add(Table)
            Next Table
        Next itm
    End If
    myOlApp = Nothing
    Return arrList
End Function
```

You can try to replicate it including a table sample in a mail body.
Has anyone a suggestion?

Thanks everyone

**EDIT:**
I tried to view source in Outlook and the correct output is the one got in VBA, I really can't see why i'm not getting the same result in VB.NET.
Can anyone help?

Comment: fwiw, the `<o:p></o:p>` elements are **NOT** standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki because this probably won't fully solve the problem (probably going to give the same result), but it's also too long for a comment. The code below re-writes some things for modern VB.Net. If this is still just an Office add-in you might not be able to use all these language features, but some of the changes (like not using ArrayList or hungarian variable prefixes) have been standard practice for more than 15 years, and it has *NEVER* been needed or at all helpful with .Net to set items to `Nothing` at the end of a method.

```vb
Function GetMailTable(Subject As String, daysAgo As Integer, ParamArray Keywords() As Object) As IEnumerable(Of mshtml.HTMLTable)
    Dim App As New Outlook.Application()
    Dim Mapi As Outlook.NameSpace = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Mapi.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

    Dim searchDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-daysAgo) 
    Dim quote As String = Chr(34)
    ' Below line assumes "Option Infer On"
    Dim filteredItems = Inbox.Items.
                   Restrict($"@SQL={quote}urn:schemas:httpmail:subject{quote} like '%{Subject}%'").
                   Restrict($"[ReceivedTime]>'{searchDate:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}'")
   
    ' Needs "Imports System.Linq" at the top
    Return filteredItems.
        Select(Function(itm) New mshtml.HTMLDocument With {.HTMLBody = itm.HTMLBody}).
        SelectMany(Function(doc)  doc.getElementsByTagName("table")).
        Cast(Of mshtml.HTMLTable)()
End Function
```

Also, the `Keywords` argument was never used. I only left it in case there's code somewhere calling the method that might break if the parameter was not defined.

Of course calling code must also adjust for the new return type. The new result can be used with a `For Each` loop, with the Linq operator methods, or as a list by appending `.ToList()` to the function call. Try to avoid the last one as much as possible.

Finally, if the `filteredItems` type, which I can't see, doesn't formally implement the right interface, you may need to [include this method](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1EWfEd) (in a separate class or module):

```
' Requires Option Strict Off, so the compiler will make the implied GetEnumerator() call :(
<Extension()> 
Public Shared Iterator Function AsEnumerable(Of T)(input As Object) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For Each item As T In input.GetEnumerator()
        Yield item
    Next
End Function
```

And then the first line of the `Return` statement like would look like this:

```
Return filteredItems.AsEnumerable(Of Outlook.MailItem)().
```

We *know* `filteredItems` will have the required `GetEnumerator()` method, or it wouldn't have worked with a `For Each` loop in the original code. It's also possible explicitly typing the initial `filteredItems` variable declaration would work to avoid this, but if you run into this problem at all I don't think it will help.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time Joel. Secondly, i tried to replace my function with yours but despite adding the Linq imports statement i get an error in the select function at '{.HTMLBody' - 'Member HTMLBody cannot be initialized in an object initializer expression because it is not a field or property'. In third place apart from old fashioned methods and syntax I don't get where my function fails getting the HTML message, but maybe this because as you might have noticed I'm still getting my way on VB.NET from VBA. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The HTML indicates that the message is plain text or RTF, not HTML. Most likely your script is accessing a message different from what VBA accessed.

Try to find the right message, select it, and use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection instead of the restricted `Items` collection as a test.

Comment: if you mean if it's accessing the same email, it is, same text, same recipients etc.

Comment: Is that the value you also see in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) when you select the message, click the Item button, and select `HTMLBody` property?

Comment: I don't see how I can add it to my Outlook ribbon, but the code I see in VBA is the same that I see when inside the message i right click and "View Source". That is the HTML that I really can't see why I'm not getting through VB.NET

Comment: As a test, have you tried to use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection instead of `Items.Restrict`?

Comment: I managed to get the correct format following your suggestion and adding the item got with restriction method to the application.activeexplorer.addtoselection method.
Sure it's not the most efficient method, so i'm still trying to figure out why i get 2 different html codes from the same mail. Did you get it?

Comment: The only explanation is that Restrict picks up a wrong item. Check its received date.

Comment: I know it could seem unreal but now I'm getting wrong format again.. I don't know what's wrong I didn't change a single thing. Restrict can't pick the wrong item since I added to selection the Item I found with Restrict method itself

Comment: I don't know. Hard to say without having access to the system.