# VB.NET Extract Excel Tables from received email body

Tags: html, excel, vb.net, outlook, excel-tables

I receive everyday an email which contains some excel tables (about 10rowsx10columns each) and I would like to have them empty keeping formats and labels intact (just erasing cell contents) and store the empty tables in a variable , or a List(Of) in order to eventually fill them.

I tried  to store them in a List(Of String) the HTML code which contains the  Tag but unfortunately I encountered a lot of various issues regarding the HTML code.

**EDIT:**

I add the post I already asked for reference, I opened another topic to find another way to accomplish my aim.

[HTML Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76622085/vb-net-incorrect-html-from-outlook-item-htmlbody)

Below the sample email content

[image]

Is there another way to do it?

Since I was asked for debugging details I attach below coding details.

```
Function GetMailTable(Subject As String, daysAgo As Integer, ParamArray Keywords() As Object)
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim Subj As String = Subject
    Dim arrList As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    daysAgo = myDate.Subtract(previousBusinessDay(myDate, daysAgo)).TotalDays
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & Subj & "%'"
    Dim filtereditemssubj As Object = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Dim filteredItems As Object = filtereditemssubj.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(myDate.AddDays(-daysAgo), "dd/MM/yyyy") + " 00:00" & "'")
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]<'" & Format(myDate.AddDays(-daysAgo).AddDays(1), "dd/MM/yyyy") + " 00:00" & "'")
    Dim htmlDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim tables As mshtml.DispHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Table As mshtml.HTMLTable
    If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then
        Found = False
    Else
        Found = True
        For Each itm In filteredItems
            htmlDoc.HTMLBody = itm.HTMLBody
            tables = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
            For Each Table In tables
                arrList.Add(Table)
            Next Table
        Next itm
    End If
    Return arrList
End Function
```

This code does not work because I can't get the HTML content of the mail.
Is there another viable way to access outlook mails' HTML content or to replicate content and layout of excel's tables included in Outlook mails' body?

Comment: Please show us the tables and the code you've written. Otherwise we really can't help as we're not a code writing service nor mind readers. Please also read [ask].

Comment: I've voted to re-open. One more vote should do it.